# Dependencies in polymer dart

Tags: dependencies, dart, polymer

A few weeks ago, I could run tute_stopwatch sample downloaded from dartlang.org. But, now, I can't even build it both in webstorm and chrome dev editor.
The error message is;

```
Dart: Get Dependencies
Incompatible version constraints on barback: - polymer 0.14.0+1 depends on version >=0.14.2 0.16.0 - pub itself depends on version >=0.13.0-dev 0.14.0
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: stopwatch
description: A sample application
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.14.0 <0.15.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

Could anyone explain the meaning of the error message above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your are using an old version of the Dart SDK (v1.5.x or below). You can upgrade it through Dart Editor, or download the latest version (1.6.0) from http://dartlang.org.

Comment: Thank you @luizmine, do you have any idea how to upgrade the dart sdk of Chrome Dev Editor?

Comment: Apparently, Chrome Dev Editor has built-in Dart tools. So we have to wait for a new release.